# Parse word doc using python to find all words with _

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am looking to parse a word document in python and I want to load that in a DataFrame (DF) to print all the words in that DF that contains a _(underscore).

Any sample code on this would be great?

I have tried multiple doc libraries but all seem to have some issue or the other to do it cleanly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Post the code you have written so far.

Comment: a) How to load a word doc in a pandas data frame? b) How to find for words in that data frame that has a _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the job:

```py
import docx2python as docp

import re

doc = docp.docx2pthon('test.docx')

bodyText = doc.text

list1 = re.findall('[a-zA-Z0-9_]asterisk symbol_[a-zA-Z0-9_]*', bodyText)
```